# Creating EULA page with conditional redirect

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, conditional

I'm trying to create "EULA" page so everyone entering some sub-site will be compered against a list of users to see if he accepted the agreement.
I'm trying to implement it by conditional redirect code that will run via Content edit web part running the attached JS code but with no luck. 
Hope someone here can help me with that.
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

var siteUrl = 'MYSITE';

function retrieveListItems() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('EULAAccepteStatus'); 
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='User' /><Value Type='User'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query>');
   this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
   clientContext.load(collListItem);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
if (oListItem.get_item('AccepteStatus')=='Accepted'){
window.location.replace('https://MYSP/SitePages/HR%20Home.aspx')
}
else {  window.location.replace('https://MYSP/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/EULA.aspx')
}
}
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to use a IDE to write your code. It will help you find easy errors like the ones you have right now.

Comment: If you set the ``EULAAccepteStatus`` List to Item Level Security so a user can only write one and read one (their own) Item, you do not need a Query as a call will only retrieve their own Item (or none). PS. Function.createDelegate is oldskool IE8 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. you are not calling *retrieveListItems()*
2. You used the wrong quotation marks (single) in the *CAML*.

Corrected code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

var siteUrl = 'MYSITE';

function retrieveListItems() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('EULAAccepteStatus'); 
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="User" /><Value Type="User"><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query>');
   this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
   clientContext.load(collListItem);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
if (oListItem.get_item('AccepteStatus')=='Accepted'){
    window.location.replace('https://MYSP/SitePages/HR%20Home.aspx')
}
else {  window.location.replace('https://MYSP/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/EULA.aspx')
}
}
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

You would have discovered the quotation mark issue with a look at the console output in the developer tools of your browser.

Also, please provide more details next time.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the help. I'm no developer and it's my first time working with JS. My goal is to create a conditional redirect based on list containing 2 columns, user (people or group field) and AccepteStatus (select cox) if the current user is on that list and the AccepteStatus is set to "Not Accepted" he need to be redirected to other page. The code I posted is from few posts I found and combined in what looked as the right way. If you have a better way to implement it I would be glad if you can post it because for now it's not working. Thanks

Comment: The corrected code I posted is working fine. I will need a bit more information in order to understand why it's not working for you. Are there any script errors showing up in the console? what does the server return when your query is executed? But, assuming that the EULAAccepteStatus list is on the same site as the page the script runs on, then try replacing _var siteUrl = 'MYSITE';_ with var _siteUrl = '/';_ and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, the problem was with the list column. It's working now. Thank for the help :)